# Django not returning JsonResponse after completing bulk_create()

Tags: python, django

Django does not return JsonResponse (or anything for that matter) after completing bulk_create(). Method is called using GET request.

Here is a simplified code which I use:

```py
objs = Entry.objects.bulk_create(entries)
print(len(objs))
return JsonResponse({'inserted': str(len(objs))})
```

This inserts `entries` into the database and I can see them in the table, `len(objs)` is visible in console, but I do not receive response. Process doesn't end and just hangs there.

Code works fine when inserting `entries` one by one, but this takes too much time since there's 1M of them.

Versions: Django 3.2.17, Python 3.10

Comment: Too much data probably. Right at the end of the request-response cycle, the database transaction will be commited and that may take some time. Test it with (significantly) fewer entries: like for starters `objs = Entry.objects.bulk_create(entries[:100])`

Comment: That worked, thank you. What can be done to reduce time to commit?

Comment: You can try to play around with `bulk_create`'s `batch_size` parameter. But, generally, for such heavy loads, I would recommend to submit the data as a whole or in batches to some asynchronous process, e.g. a celery worker that will then write the data to the database.

Comment: The other option is of course to try and scale your database: more memory, more cpu, etc. Check what configuration options there are for your particular db.

Comment: I agree with user2390182, such heavy tasks are normally not implemented in an user request cycle. If this is still necessary implement some async processes. Or if these are one time tasks, you can also implement some Django management commands etc.